# Overloads Overrides with an Optional Parameter

Tags: vb.net

So i have a base class and an inheriting class.

BASE CLASS

```
Friend Overridable Overloads Sub ProcessRecords(ByVal oDataKeyValuePair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Double)), ByVal oFilterValues As SDFilterCriteria.FilterType)
    'does stuff'
End Sub

Friend Overridable Overloads Sub ProcessRecords(ByVal oDataKeyValuePair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Double)), ByVal oFilterValues As SDFilterCriteria.FilterType, Optional ByVal MaxCount As Integer = 0)
    'does stuff'
End Sub
```

CHILD CLASS

```
Friend Overloads Overrides Sub ProcessRecords(ByVal oDataKeyValuePair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Double)), ByVal oFilterValues As SDFilterCriteria.FilterType, Optional ByVal MaxCount As Integer = 0)
    'does other stuff
End Sub
```

But when I build i get

> **Error   6**
>
> 'Friend Overrides Overloads Sub ProcessRecords(oDataKeyValuePair As System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String,
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Double)),
>   oFilterValues As SharedModels.FilterCriteriaBase.FilterType, [MaxCount
>   As Integer = 0])' **cannot override** 'Friend Overridable Overloads Sub
>   ProcessRecords(oDataKeyValuePair As
>   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String,
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Double)),
>   oFilterValues As SharedModels.FilterCriteriaBase.FilterType)' **because
>   they differ by optional parameters.**

I have a feeling it's because of the overloads but i can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

It's because except for the optional parameter, both method signatures are identical. So if you call the method without specifying that last parameter, there's no way for it to tell which method you meant to call. Are you calling the one with the optional parameter but leaving out the optional parameter, or are you calling the method that doesn't have the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear. The compiler thinks that you would like to override the overloaded method without the optional parameter.

I think you should remove the overloaded method without the optional parameter in the base class as it does not make any sense anyway.

There are two options:

- The 2 overloaded methods remain but the `MaxCount` parameter must be required and the one without this parameter should call the other one specifying a default value for the required `MaxCount` parameter.
- Only the second method remains with the optional `MaxCount` parameter.

You can choose from these options whichever fits your needs. After that the override should work.